# ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in endog, estimation infeasible. in GLM model

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

I am using statsmodel GLM for linear prediction. This is the code that I set exog and endog

```
X_train = claim_data_x.iloc[:,5:].values
Y_train = claim_data_x.loc[:,'LOSS_AMOUNT'].values
num_claims = claim_data_x.loc[:,'CLAIM_FREQ'].values
X_test = claim_data_y.iloc[:,5:].values
```

While creating model no any error raise:

```
glm_model = sm.GLM(endog=Y_train, exog=X_train, family= sm.families.Gamma(link=sm.families.links.log()), offset = np.log(num_claims))
```

But while fitting train data to see the summary output I face with error:

```
glm_model.fit().summary(xname = list(data_x.iloc[:,6:].columns))
```

**ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in endog, estimation infeasible.**

Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: is there any NaN or inf value? what does `np.isfinite(Y_train).all()` return?

Comment: @Paul no, there is no any nan or inf value